# Getting $_POST with Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, html, forms, post, joomla

Here is my form, it looks correct, so this shoulnd't be an issue , I also removed the enctype to make sure it wasn't that.

```
    <form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_woo&task=hello.create'); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
      <p>
        Project Name : 
        <input style="width:30%;" name="name" id="name"/>
        <input style="display:none;" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $user->id;?>"/>
        <input style="display:none;" id="county" name="county"/>
        <input style="display:none;" id="state" name="state"  />
      </p>
      <button type="submit" class="btn-green" id="select_county">Create Project</button>
    </form>
```

Inside ControllerHello

```
    public function create()
    {
       $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
       $foo = $jinput->get('state', '', 'filter');
       print_r($foo);
       die;
    }
```

Returns "NULL"

Any ideas?

Comment: As per your input field of `state` has sets to `display:none`, whenever the form will submit it's send the blank input into `state` that's the reason why you are getting `null` instead of value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$input = new JInput;
$name = $input->get('name', '', 'post');
$country = $input->get('country', '', 'post');
// etc.
```

Then you can use a series of JInput class methods for specific purposes:

```
 // method      integer  getInt()       getInt($name, $default = null)    Get a signed integer.
 // method      integer  getUint()      getUint($name, $default = null)   Get an unsigned integer.
 // method      float    getFloat()     getFloat($name, $default = null)  Get a floating-point number.
 // method      boolean  getBool()      getBool($name, $default = null)   Get a boolean.
 // method      string   getWord()      getWord($name, $default = null)
 // method      string   getAlnum()     getAlnum($name, $default = null)
 // method      string   getCmd()       getCmd($name, $default = null)
 // method      string   getBase64()    getBase64($name, $default = null)
 // method      string   getString()    getString($name, $default = null)
 // method      string   getHtml()      getHtml($name, $default = null)
 // method      string   getPath()      getPath($name, $default = null)
 // method      string   getUsername()  getUsername($name, $default = null)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try this -

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$post_array = $input->getArray($_POST);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the best option to get entire $_POST with JInput is

```
JFactory::getApplication()->input->post->getArray();
```

If you want to get specific array (called 'jform' for example) from the request, then use

```
JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('jform', array(), 'ARRAY');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get Values from a Specific Super Global

```
$foo = $jinput->get->get('varname', 'default_value', 'filter');

$foo = $jinput->post->get('varname', 'default_value', 'filter');

$foo = $jinput->server->get('varname', 'default_value', 'filter');
```

For more information go to [Retrieving request data using JInput](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput)

Answer (score -2):

You could try changing your form action to:

```
<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_woo&view=hello&task=create');
```

Since your task is called create not hello.create it might work better this way....

Then I always just did

```
$post = JRequest::get('post');
print_r($post['state']);
```

Comment: `JRequest` is deprecated as of Joomla 1.7 is believe. Not that you're wrong but it's better practice to use something like the following: `$post = new JInput($_POST);` for Joomla 2.5 onwards ;)

Comment: Lodders correct. See here for more info on JInput http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput